# PHP arrays - simple query

Tags: php, arrays

Ok I know this is simple, in fact damn simple, I did this in the last project about a week ago, but I don't know why it has skipped off my head.

Input:

```
$word = "stack";
```

What I want to do is:

```
$array = array("s", "t", "a", "c", "k");
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: for information, you can do this : $foo = 'bar'; echo $foo[1]; //will print 'a';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[str_split();](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

Comment: I feel so stupid..DAMN

Thanks for fast reply, needed urgently!

Comment: Don't feel bad. It can be hard to find these PHP functions and there are a lot of them, more than most people know.

Answer (score 3):

Your question isn't too clear, but I suspect you want to turn your string into an array. You don't have to, actually. You can just access $word as if it were an array:

```
$word = 'stack';
for ($i=0, $m = strlen($word); $i < $m; $i++)
    echo $word[$i], "\n";
```

Comment: What if he wants to use `foreach` with that string? In PHP, strings are half-arrays, unfortunately.

Comment: Well, that'd be an odd way of going about things (I want to loop over this string, but it HAS to be foreach even though a for-loop would do). 

But, indeed, there are cases where you are better off using str_split(). But if at all possible I'd favor not using str_split() as it creates a new array and `strlen($word)` new strings.

Comment: I guess I figured it out why certain PHP aspects are so bad. Because people don't care about them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var_dump(str_split("abc"));
```